# How to select all column value in mysql with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have table with two columns : "Total" and "Returned" I am trying to take all column values from both but it not work with me. It takes only the first row in the column I want total values in the column

My code :

```
 Private Sub TotalTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TotalTextBox.TextChanged
    Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Pwd=password"

    Using net As New MySqlConnection(str)

        Dim totalnet As String = "Select * from testata where Qty_Returned and Total" 

        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(totalnet, net)

        net.Open()
        Dim rdnet As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

        If rdnet.Read() Then
            Label16.Text = rdnet.GetString(12) - rdnet.GetString(11)
        Else

        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no table in your code.

Comment: You are only calling `Read` once so you are only reading one record. There rae plenty of examples around of using a data reader. I suggest that you consult some of them.

Comment: That said, how are you expecting to display multiple rows in a single `Label`?

Comment: By the way, you should be using a

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want to show the result of total - returned in the label. any suggestion of type of read because I am fresh with mysql.

Comment: If you want to sum the difference between those two columns then you should be doing that in your SQL and just retrieving that single value.  You would then call `ExecuteScalar` on your command to get that one value rather than `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you got it working. Just a few suggestions...
Turn on Option Strict for this and all your code.
Comments are inline.

```
Private Sub testdataDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles testataDataGridView.DataBindingComplete
        'A Using...End Using block will ensure that your objects that use unmanages 
        'resources are closed and disposed event if there is an error in the code
        Using con As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testdb;   Uid=root;Pwd=1234")
            'A command object constructor can take an query string and connection as arguments
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select sum(Qty_Returned) FROM testdata", con)
                'Open the connection at the last possible minute
                con.Open()
                Dim sqlresult = cmd.ExecuteScalar
                Label16.Text = sqlresult.ToString
            End Using
            Using cmg As New MySqlCommand("select sum(Total) FROM testgdata", con)
                Dim sqlresult2 = cmg.ExecuteScalar
                Label10.Text = sqlresult2.ToString
            End Using
        End Using
        Label18.Text = (CInt(La
End Sub
```

Not sure why this code is in this event.

Comment: Thanks for your valued editing and it worked for me...thanks

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution with this code:

```
 Private Sub testdataDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As     DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles testataDataGridView.DataBindingComplete
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testdb;   Uid=root;Pwd=1234")

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim cmg As New MySqlCommand

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "select sum(Qty_Returned) FROM testdata"
    Dim sqlresult As Object
    sqlresult = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    Dim str1 As String
    str1 = sqlresult
    Label16.Text = str1
    cmg.Connection = con
    cmg.CommandText = "select sum(Total) FROM testgdata"
    Dim sqlresult2 As Object
    sqlresult2 = cmg.ExecuteScalar
    Dim str2 As String
    str2 = sqlresult2
    Label10.Text = str2

    Label18.Text = Label10.Text - Label16.Text
End Sub
```